# UIActivityViewController Activity Items order of appearance

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiactivity

I have a `UIActivityViewController` with system activities as well as Custom `UIActivities`. Can I have the `UIActivityViewController` show up items in a particular order? i.e I want the custom UIActivity appear first in the list of activity items in front of the system activity like `UIActivityTypeSaveToCameraRoll`.

Comment: any luck for solution?

Comment: Nope. Ended up using a custom control.